# What is the definition of $H^{-k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and its norm?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

What is the definition of $H^{-k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and its norm? How can I understand the fact $$\|f\|_{H^{-k}(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\|(I-\triangle)^{-k}f\|_{H^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $\|f,H^s\| =\|(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\hat f(\xi),L_2\| $, where $\hat f$ is a Fourier transform of $f$.

In addition, $\hat{\Delta f} = -|\xi|^2\hat f$ (up to a constant factor depending on you definition of Fourier transform), so if $k\in \mathbb N$
$$\|(I-\Delta)^k g,H^{-k}\|=\|(1+|\xi|^2)^{-k/2}\times(1+|\xi|^2)^k\hat g(\xi),L_2 \|$$
$$=\|(1+|\xi|^2)^{k/2} \hat g(\xi),L_2 \|=\|g,H^k\|,$$ which replies to your second question.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! Is there a "nice" book or lecture for further learning this theory？

Comment: @A.Hoo You are welcome. Sorry, I can't give you any references. Maybe this one from wikipedia could be useful: Evans, L.C. (1998), Partial Differential Equations, AMS_Chelsea

Comment: @ TZakrevskiy: Thanks again! :)